# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to Server

Tags: vb.net

I usually connect to MySQL via odbc but in this special instance I need to connect via sqlconnection and binding it to a dropdown. Here's my script

```
Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=101.99.69.30; Database=recon; User ID=recon; PASSWORD=recon123;")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT fid, fmake, fmodel FROM treconcalculation")
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim ds As New DataSet()
                    sda.Fill(ds)
                    vehicle1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                    vehicle1.DataTextField = "fmodel"
                    vehicle1.DataValueField = "fid"
                    vehicle1.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        vehicle1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select Customer--", "0"))
```

The problem is, it gives me this error at line 19.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Source Error: 



Line 17:                 Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Line 18:                     Dim ds As New DataSet()
Line 19:                     sda.Fill(ds)
Line 20:                     vehicle1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
Line 21:                     vehicle1.DataTextField = "fmodel"
```

I've confirmed with the odbc string I usually use and the source, database, user id and password is correct. what seems to be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to any of the below issues.

```
1) Network issue
2) SQL Server configuration issue
3) Firewall issue
4) Client driver issue
5) Application configuration issue
6) Authentication and logon issue
```

Some ways to check this:

```
1. Check if your SQL has started: 
Start->Control Panel -> Administration Tools -> Services.
Find the firewall service here to see if it is disabled.
If not, right click the service and select Stop from the context menu.

2. Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections:
a) Open SQL Server Management Studio. 
b) Right click SQL Server instance -> Properties -> Connections ->  Check the Allow remote connections to this server box. 
c) Go to the General section and check name of SQL Server specified in the Name field.
```

Comment: Hi, it's actually on a server and unreachable to me. I could connect to the server via ODBC with the same credentials. is there anything else I can try? Thanks

Comment: Check if this helps: http://www.technologycrowds.com/2014/02/could-not-open-connection-to-sql-server.html

Comment: Hi, I don't even have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on the machine. should I install it? by the way, isn't ODBC also connecting remotely? thanks

Comment: Are you using that DB? then how are you trying to connect to it when it is not even there in your machine?

Comment: The scripts are uploaded to a shared server. i'm not trying to connect to localhost.